# Get API auth_token token to renew weekly

Tags: plugin-development, api

I have a wordpress website that connects to experience.com api to get account stats and data. everything is working fine besides the auth_token needing to be renewed every 10 days. Right now it is all hardcoded to the page so I manually have to change the auth token once a week on a few pages. I would like the auth_token to auto renew daily or weekly.

My goal is to create a plugin to get the auth_token everyday or once a week so this process can be automated.

Is there a way to get the auth_token and store it somewhere and have the page look for that token on load?

```
  function experience_auth() {

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.experience.com/v2/core/login?User_email=email@example.com.com&Password=password',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "user_email": "email@example.com.com",
        "password": "password"
    }',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;

  }
  add_action( 'experience_auth_token', 'experience_auth' );
```

Comment: "Is there a way to get the auth_token and store it somewhere and have the page look for that token on load?" - simple answer: yes. Have you read the documentation? [You could store/retrieve the value via the Options API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/options-api/) and [renew it via Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/). What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I have created the cron job to run the action everyday. The problem is the coding to get the auth token and storing it.

Comment: So your `experience_auth()` is not working? What errors do you get? For storing and retrieval, check my above link to the options API

Comment: The experience_auth() works i'm just not sure what code to add to that to get it to do what i need.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.